# Auto column divs with a max-height parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I need to align columns, with divs that have a set width inside a parent that has a max-height of the screensize.

So, for example:

```
[div]
[div]
[div]
[div]
```

Would be the max height, but if we go an extra div it needs to do this:

```
[div][new_div]
[div]
[div]
[div]
```

and so on. So once it hits the max height (of the screensize, or whatever) the divs needs to auto column over and align to the top right.

In summary:

A maximum of 2 columns, filled with data that stacks upon eachother [one after the other, veritcally]. Once it hits the max width [which is the screensize] I need it to automatically create a new column to hold the new rows.

Comment: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: I'd _like_ to do this w/ only CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm...that's tricky. You might be able to use [CSS3 columns](http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/) to pull this off, though they aren't supported in IE as far as I know.

Since you said your `<div>`s have a set width, you could make that width the width of the column. Then when the stack of `<div>s` fill up the allotted vertical space, they should overflow into a new column.

Comment: Right, but why would setting the parent's width to the child's width work?

Comment: Not sure I follow you...I didn't say anything about the parent `<div>`. I said make the width of the _column_ the width of the `<div>`. The parent `<div>` would have the `max-height`.

Comment: Hmm I think I get what you mean. I'm doing it with just the parent, then filling it in with divs. Perhaps I should set a column child, then? Think you could jsFiddle something real quick?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8rrfu/2/ This works as long as the number of `<div>`s is even. I put a width on `#parent` just so the column gap remains at 10px, just for the sake of example, since otherwise it'll widen to fit the container.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Going to need to tweak it, because there's no telling how many will be per column/group :(

Comment: Yeah I don't think this would work. The divs need to go there automatically, based on width, and just as to how much data there is vs screensize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working demo](http://www.stack.no/dump/float_top.html) using right `float: right`, and then `transform: rotate` to emulate up/down-floating. With some work you could make this work in all major browsers, you'd just have to apply different rotation filters for the different platforms.

The resulting code can be a bit confusing to work with, as the width becomes the height and visa versa, but it might still be a better solution than moving the `div` around with javascript.

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <style type="text/css">
      #outer {
       width: 500px;
       margin: 300px 0 0 -200px;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      }
      .inner {
       background-color: red;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       float: right;
       margin: 10px;
       -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
     </style>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div id="outer">
      <div class="inner">1</div>
      <div class="inner">2</div>
      <div class="inner">3</div>
      <div class="inner">4</div>
      <div class="inner">5</div>
      <div class="inner">6</div>
      <div class="inner">7</div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I get it, but this wouldn't help for dynamicness would it? I mean, it's just flipping it around. Intriguing solution, though. I'm going to think about this. I guess it would allow for you to build the data normally, but instead of going from L->R it'd be R->L, and so it would do it "automatically".. This might be the winner!